# How to make child and parent processes manipulate the same global variable?

Tags: c, linux, signals, ipc

I have a boolean variable "ab" that is set to false, but I want to change it to true in the function that the child process executes. I tried using pipes but I didn't what to do exactly and how. can anyone help me, please?

the code creates 2 child processes and enters an infinite loop of sending signals to both child processes after 3s using `alarm(3)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

void passage(int);
void AB(int);
void BA(int);

bool ab = true;

int pid[2];
int i = 1;

void
passage(int signum)
{
    printf("Voiture %d passée\n", i);
    i++;
    ab = !ab;
}

void
AB(int sig)
{

    if (ab == false) {
        printf("feu1: ROUGE | feu2: VERT\n");
        ab = true;
    }
}

void
BA(int sig)
{

    if (ab == true) {
        // ab = false;
        printf("feu1: VERT | feu2: ROUGE\n");
    }
}

int
main()
{

    struct sigaction action;

    action.sa_handler = passage;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &action, NULL);

    pid[0] = fork();
    if (pid[0] != -1) {
        if (pid[0] == 0) {
            // Code du child 1
            printf("test1\n");
            signal(SIGUSR1, AB);
            while (1);

        }
        else {
            pid[1] = fork();
            if (pid[1] == 0) {
                // Code child 2
                printf("test2\n");
                signal(SIGUSR2, BA);
                while (1);

            }
            else {
                // parent precessus
                // send signals to the two childs after 3s
                printf("PONT OUVERT\n");

                for (;;) {
                    alarm(3);
                    pause();
                    kill(pid[0], SIGUSR1);
                    kill(pid[1], SIGUSR2);

                }
                // gcc test.c -o test
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to use shared memory, take a look at the `shmemXXX` functions.

Comment: Do you want [infinite] signals to be sent? Or, is that part of the problem? To share memory between parent and child, in parent [before `fork`], use `shmget` et. al. [SysV IPC].

Comment: A better solution might be a semaphore.

Comment: You can use threads instead of processes. Then the global memory space will be shared between all the threads (cf. pthread_create()).